# Paperclip multiple file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip

I have three model:

```
 class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :tickets, dependent: :delete_all
 end

 class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  attr_accessible :description, :title,:asset  
  has_many :assets
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets
end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body
  belongs_to :ticket
  has_attached_file :asset
end
```

_form:

```
<%= form_for([@project,@ticket], html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
</p>

<% number = 0 %>
<%= f.fields_for :assets do |asset| %>
    <p>
        <%= asset.label "File ##{number +=1}" %>
        <%= asset.file_field :asset %>
    </p>
<% end %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

TicketsController:

```
def new
 @ticket = @project.tickets.build
 3.times { @ticket.assets.build }
end
```

**The problem is when I try to create new ticket for a project it shows  ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError at /projects/1/tickets/new
unknown attribute: ticket_id**
@ticket= id: nil, title: nil, description: nil, project_id: 1, created_at: nil,   updated_at: nil, user_id: nil

From error message I can see that tickets "id" is nil(it's not yet created), so assets don't have ticket_id, so how do I get around it?

Comment: This kind of nested form is a feature of `nested_form` gem. Are you including it on your `Gemfile`?

Comment: No, I am only using paperclip

Comment: nested_form gem is not essential here since he is building assets manually on the action file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
attr_accessible :ticket_id
```

You need to add this field as attr accessible on its model.

For nested attribuetes 
you also need to add project_assets as attr_accessibl/ attr_accessor

```
attr_accessible :project_assets
attr_accessor :project_assets
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use nested_form gem for assets and you have to create an attribute of ticket_id in assets database table to work association properly.

Comment: but it is possible with out using nested form gem

Comment: yes it is possible without using nested_form but i think better way to do this is using nested_gem